# Class 'EventManager' not found

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm trying to learn about Events in Doctrine, but when I read [the docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html), I get stuck at the very first line:

```
$evm = new EventManager();
```

Here I get a

> PHP Fatal error: Class 'EventManager' not found

How can I solve this issue?

Here is the complete code:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;

require_once("Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Setup.php");
Setup::registerAutoloadPEAR();

$classLoader = new Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Entities', __DIR__);
$classLoader->register();

$paths = array();
$isDevMode = true;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
$dbParams = array("driver" => "pdo_mysql",
    "host" => variable_get("dbManip_host"),
    "user" => variable_get("dbManip_user"),
    "password" => variable_get("dbManip_password"),
    "dbname" => variable_get("dbManip_dbName"),
    "charset" => "utf8");
global $entityManager_globalObject;
$entityManager_globalObject = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
$entityManager_globalObject->getConnection()->exec("SET NAMES UTF8");

$evm = new EventManager();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for class [`Doctrine\Common\EventManager`](https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/2.3/lib/Doctrine/Common/EventManager.php).

```
$evm = new \Doctrine\Common\EventManager();
```

or

```
use Doctrine\Common\EventManager; // at the top of your file

$evm = new EventManager();
```

Comment: That was surprisingly simple (error is gone). Any reason why they didn't put that working code in the docs instead of what is there right now (non-working code)?

Comment: @Shawn probably something that has been overseen. All the type-hints lead to that class though, so it shouldn't be hard to spot what it should look like. Also, you can either report an issue on the issue tracker at http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/ or open a pull request against the documentation at https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/tree/master/docs